# Make Function More Generalizable for Column Names For Different Dataframes

Tags: python

I have a function like this:

```
def create_percent_column(a, b, c): 
dataframes_list = [a, b, c]
results = []
cols = []
for df in dataframes_list:
    df = (df.filter(cols).groupby([df['Name'], df['Type'],df['Date']]).
          agg(lambda x: x.eq(4).sum()/x.count()))
    df = df.reset_index()
    results.append(df)
return results

cols = ['Flames', 'Canucks', 'Oilers', 'Sharks', 'Wings', 'Chiefs']
create_percent_column(a, b, c)
new_a, new_b, new_c = create_percent_column(a, b, c)

print(new_a)
```

I want to apply my function to a list of columns shown as cols. In the future, I want to alter the column names in the list. How can I make sure the function can still perform with different column names. Right now, this is not working.

This is what I am doing right now:

```
def inner_function(a, grouper=None, cols=None):
    if not grouper:
       grouper = ['Name', 'Division', 'Date']
    if not cols:
       cols = df.columns.difference(grouper)
return (a.groupby(grouper)[cols]
         .agg(lambda x: x.eq(4).sum()/x.count())
         .reset_index()
         .melt(id_vars=grouper,
               value_vars=cols)
       )

  def create_percent_column_many(a, b, c, grouper=None, cols=None):
  return [inner_function(d, grouper, cols) for d in dfs]

 new_a, new_b, new_c = create_percent_column_many(a, b, c)
```

This ^ does not work.

Comment: Have `cols` as a function parameter?

Comment: Well, I suppose but I ideally want to pass different dataframes to the function.

Comment: Isn't `a` the dataframe? you are already doing it...

Comment: Can you provide examples of *how* you would like to use the function? Also what is expected to be fixed and variable?

Comment: I've redone my code a bit and elaborated more. Basically, I am trying to see how my function can be applied to a list of specific columns. Ideally, the list of columns can be updated manually by me to have different column names, but the function should still do what it needs to do.

Comment: Also, 'a', 'b', 'c' are three different dataframes I need to pass to my function.

Comment: OK, then I'd use two functions, one to work for **one** dataframe, and one to wrap the logic for many dataframes (see below). Of course you can also write a single function to directly work on many dataframes but that's less explicit IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the grouping columns (`['Name', 'Division', 'Date']`) are fixed, you could rewrite your function to take the columns as an optional parameter and to automatically detect the columns to process as the [`difference`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html) to the grouping columns:

```
def create_percent_column_single(x, cols=None):
    grouper = ['Name', 'Division', 'Date']
    if not cols:
        cols = x.columns.difference(grouper)
    return (x.groupby(grouper)[cols]
             .agg(lambda x: x.eq(4).sum()/x.count())
             .reset_index()
             .melt(id_vars=grouper,
                   value_vars=cols)
           )
```

Then call it with:

```
create_percent_column(df)

# or
create_percent_column_single(df, cols=['Flames', 'Canucks', 'Sharks', 'Oilers'])
```

If you have many dataframes, I'd then write a wrapper function:

```
def create_percent_column(*dfs):
    return list(map(create_percent_column_single, dfs))

new_a, new_b, new_c = create_percent_column(a, b, c)
```

If the grouper columns are also variable:

```
def create_percent_column_single(x, grouper, cols=None)
    # rest of function without manually defining
    # grouper = ['Name', 'Division', 'Date']
    # ...

def create_percent_column(*dfs, grouper, cols=None):
    return [create_percent_column_single(x, grouper, cols) for x in dfs]
```

#### full code

```
def create_percent_column_single(x, grouper=None, cols=None):
    if not grouper:
        grouper = ['Name', 'Division', 'Date']
    if not cols:
        cols = x.columns.difference(grouper)
    return (x.groupby(grouper)[cols]
             .agg(lambda x: x.eq(4).sum()/x.count())
             .reset_index()
             .melt(id_vars=grouper,
                   value_vars=cols)
           )

def create_percent_column(*dfs, grouper=None, cols=None):
    return [create_percent_column_single(x, grouper, cols) for x in dfs]

new_a, new_b, new_c = create_percent_column(a, b, c)
```

if you want to change the grouper

```
new_a, new_b, new_c = create_percent_column(a, b, c,
                                            grouper=['other', 'columns'])
```

Comment: Thanks! In my case, I have several dataframes to pass (a, b, c) and the Name, Division and Date columns are fixed. But column names can change. Would i use the wrapper functions for this? Your first solutions seems very good but it only takes in dataframe 'a', when I would want to pass dataframe 'b' and 'c' as well.

Comment: Yes, this should work. Give it a try and comment if this doesn't behave as expected (ideally with a reproducible example of your 3 inputs)

Comment: You need to use the **wrapper** function `create_percent_column_many(a, b, c)`

Comment: Okay - would you mind writing out the code in full, please. Still learning and it would be very useful.

Comment: Sure, see update

Comment: Have you given it a try?

Comment: Hey there! Yes, I'm having issues with it. In create_percent_column, why are we only passing 'a'. I want to pass 'b' and 'c' as well. Also inside the first function, there is a df and a variables - which don't work.  Additionally - this does not work when you pass multiple dataframes when we only passed 'a' to the first function. def create_percent_column_many(*dfs, grouper=None, cols=None):
    return [create_percent_column(d, grouper, cols) for d in dfs] - Here also, what is d?

Comment: @Skywalker5032 no, you don't want to pass more than one dataframe in `create_percent_column`, use `create_percent_column_many` for that. If this is just the name that is an issue to you, rename what I called `create_percent_column` as `inner_function`.

Comment: Why don't I post what I have and you can take a look - that might be easier.

Comment: @Skywalker5032 I renamed the functions so that `create_percent_column` is the function to which you should pass the many dataframes. Please give it a try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255571/discussion-between-skywalker5032-and-mozway).